# Как сделать так, что бы проект на GitHub pages запускался с определенной квери строкой и отдавал нужную страницу?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, github-pages

Есть проект залитый на GitHub.
Если открыть проект по ссылке и начать "путешествовать": т.е. открывать разные роуты, например логин, каталог и тд. - меняются роутом в квери строке и в зависимости от этого отдаются разные страницы.
Но если ввести адрес проекта сразу с определенной квери строкой - падает ошибка 404 "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."

Как сделать так, что бы проект запускался с определенной квери строкой и отдавал нужную страницу?

Comment: можно ссылку на проект?

Comment: Нашел решение: нужно заменить BrowserRouter на HashRouter ( с react-router-dom)